# How can i change the textbox value on pressing space?

Tags: javascript

I want to change the English words into Hindi
every time I press space in textbox its a keypress event but how to apply only for space key.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#textboxid').keypress(function(e){    
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
             if(code == 32) { //space keycode
               //Do language transilation here
             }
        });
     });
    </script>


    <form id="form1" name="form1">
      <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textboxid" />
    </form>
```

Comment: sorry i forget to add the argument in function.

Comment: and how to call that function through input type text ?? i m new into this

Comment: you should include the jquery library and give an id to text box say textboxid and use the above function. i edited the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Space is **32**. So using [jQuery keypress event](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) you can do it with:

```
$("textarea").on("keypress", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: OP did not mention jQuery. You should at least explain that you use it and what it is...

Comment: @FelixKling, it's hard to explain what is jQuery in couple of words but I hope the link to docs will help the author :)

Answer (score 0):

For a vanilla js answer:

```
document.getElementById( 'textboxid' ).onkeypress = function( e ) {
    if ( e.keyCode === 32 ) {
        // Translate into Hindi
    }
}
```